# Cannot Comprehend Requirement

Tags: c++, algorithm

I'm trying to brush up my algorithmic skills and came across this problem. Here goes: http://opc.iarcs.org.in/index.php/problems/LEADGAME

My code is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int count;
    cin >> count;

    int winningP = 1; // winning player
    int lead = 0; // lead

    for (int i=0; i < count; i++)
    {
        int scoreA, scoreB = 0;
        cin >> scoreA >> scoreB;

        int l;
        if (scoreA > scoreB)
            l = scoreA - scoreB;
        else
            l = scoreB - scoreA;

        if (l > lead) // greater lead than what's been processed
        {
            lead = l;
            winningP = scoreA > scoreB ? 1 : 2;
        }
    }

    cout << winningP << " " << lead;

    return 0;
}
```

However, on the website, when I submit my code for evaluation, it prints out that my program is giving wrong answers. What am I doing wrong here? The sample input and outputs have been verified.

Comment: Have you tried other inputs and outputs besides the example? Are you sure the formatting of your output is correct?

Comment: It could be as simple as a missing newline at the end?

Comment: I did try other inputs and outputs and get the right answers according to how it should behave unless I'm mis-interpreting the question itself. As for missing newline, I tried adding that but to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are solving a different problem. You find the player who won any round by the biggest margin (and that margin). In the problem, the scores of the rounds are accumulated, so if, as in the example, player 1 wins the first round by 58 and loses the second by 45, after two rounds, player1 still leads by 13.

Comment: Oh, so the scores are getting accumulated. Didn't look into that. Thank you!